# What is the better way to handle mutiple intents in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

We come across the following code or something similar in Android or Java many times. This code seems like containing repetitions and this is not a good practice at all. There must be some better way to do this. is there any shorter code to achieve this?

```
 Intent intent=null;
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.details:
            intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.apply:
            intent = new Intent(this, ApplyActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.edit:
            intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.upload:
            intent = new Intent(this, UploadActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.call:
            intent = new Intent(this, CallActivity.class);
            break;
    }
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Use intent.setClassName instead

Comment: @Amy that's actually great idea. thanks

Comment: Should I post an answer for it?

Comment: See updated answer it actually simple and shorten :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a table of ids to activity classes in a static initializer or constructor:

```
HashMap<Integer, Class<?>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(R.id.foo, Foo.class);  // repeat for each id/class pair
```

Then use the map instead of a switch:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this), map.get(v.getId()));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented use `setClass` method instead. Do like this.

Set your `Activity` classname to button tag and get this tag on `button` click.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="YourActivityName"
/>
```

Java Code

```
 String classname = (String) textView.getTag();
 intent.setClassName(getPackageName().toString(), classname) 
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ofcourse. This is not a good practise at all. Try to achieve generalization.

Below is what I put into practice.

Just a think, **Why I would write the code again, when it is already written..!!**

Thinking that way,

1. Put all the common code in to a common class
2. Extend that class
3. Use its members

Create a class, say `BaseAppCompatActivity.java` as below:

```
public abstract class BaseAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());
        initiateViews();
    }

    protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

    protected abstract void initiateViews();

    public void setHasToolBar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }

    public Toolbar getToolBar() {
        return mToolbar;
    }

    public void setHasTabLayout() {
        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    }

    public TabLayout getTabLayout() {
        return mTabLayout;
    }

    public void showProgressDialog() {
        showProgressDialog("Please Wait ...");
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(String message) {
        // progress bar not null and is visible, so set the title
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(message);
        }
        // create new progress bar
        else {
            mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", message, true, false);
        }
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public void showAlertDialog(String message) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void logInformation(Class tag, String description) {
        Log.i(tag.getName(), description);
    }

    public void logError(Class tag, String description) {
        Log.e(tag.getName(), description);
    }

    public void logDebug(Class tag, String description) {
        Log.d(tag.getName(), description);
    }

    public void launchActivity(Class<? extends Activity> cls, Bundle bundle, int code) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (bundle != null)
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.setClass(activity, cls);
        if (code == -1)
            startActivity(intent);
        else
            startActivityForResult(intent, code);

    }

    public void loadFragment(Class fragmentClass, boolean addToBackStack) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            if (addToBackStack) {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(fragmentClass.getSimpleName())
                        .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragmentClass.getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment, fragmentClass.getSimpleName())
                        .commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And after that, extend all your activities to this `BaseAppCompatActivity` class.

Then, in your code in activity is cut down to just

```
launchActivity(Activity2.class, null, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag equal your activity :

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:tag="DetailsActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:tag="ApplyActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:tag="EditActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:tag="EditActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:tag="DetailsActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:tag="CallActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dnt want this text" />
```

Java code this :  Your package name :`com.example.pkg1`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.example.pkg1", "com.example.pkg1."+v.getTag() );
startActivity(intent);
```